# how use and invalidate session in java web?

Tags: java, session, web

In my web application, I use a session to store the information of the user that is changing, and in the database I update this data only at the end of the session, for this I use the HttpsessionListener and everything works well, but when the user logs back to their account,then there are data from the last session, I do not know what's the matter.

When a user logs in to the account:

```
String name = request.getParameter(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USERNAME);
    String password = request.getParameter(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_PASSWORD);
    String page;
    User user;
    try {
        user = userService.find(name, password); //I get data from the database
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        log.error("Exception occurred in Login command ", e);
        request.setAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_MESSAGE, Messages.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
        return PagePath.PAGE_INFO;
    }

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER, user);
    page = "controller?command=goToHome";

    return page;
```

and my sessionListener:

```
public class UserListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        HttpSession session = e.getSession();
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER);
        DAOFactory factory = new MySqlDAOFactory();
        UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl(factory.getUserDAO());
        userService.update(user);
        session.removeAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Http session is not exactly what you think it is. It doesn't represent only one log in. Those objects might be stored on user's end and even shared between servers.

Comment: but I invalidate it and remove attribute. Why it isn't work?

Comment: I don't see `invalidate()` being called anywhere.

Comment: I invalidate session when user logout and I setup session timeout

Comment: if I add invalidate() in sessionListener it  isn't work anyway

Comment: That's because `sessionDestroyed` already called after session invalidation.

Comment: yes so I don't call invalidate() in sessionDestroyed(). invalidate is called when user logout and when session timeout is up or I should call invalidate() in other place

Comment: You say "when the user logs back to their account,then there are data from the last session".  What data are you seeing?  Other attributes stored in the session?  Have you printed out everything in the session after login?

Comment: The session stores the name, the registration date and the user's rating, which changes during the existence of the session and is updated in the database only when the session is destroyed. The problem is that when a user enters repeatedly in their account, the rating from the last session will be displayed although the rating has been updated in the database.